# How to make a print() function that could print and argument OR another

Tags: python, operators

I want to make the print statement randomly pick between 2 arguments, I  tried using the OR within the brackets and I also tried using the OR outside the brackets with a new print() function --> (print() or print()), both of these methods print both the arguments at once, I tried to look for a different solution but I expected to use the random module for that problem, is there a way  to use the OR within the print function itself?

```
if guess < number:
    print("This is a little bit low, try a bigger number" or "Number is too low")

if guess > number:
    print("This is kinda high try a smaller number" or "Try a smaller number")
```

Answer (score 3):

`or` doesn't randomly select one of the arguments. It evaluates to the first truthful value (or the last value evaluated). If you want a random message, you can make an expression that chooses one using the ternary-if operator

```
from random import random
print("a message" if random() < 0.5 else "another message")
```

Better yet, the `random` module provides a `choice` function, which randomly chooses one element of a list.

```
from random import choice
messages = ['a message', 'another message', 'yet another']
print(choice(messages))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll go off with the second option as it suits my need well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MinaBasem: thanks. please accept answer if it solves the problem